Is there a recommended Log4J2 pattern for logging individual jobs to individual files?
We have a platform that uses Log4J to write logs for individual jobs that run on our platform. We do this by creating a new Logger for each job:
logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getPackage().getName() + '.' + name + '.' + dateTime);
However, the Usage page in the Log4J2 manual states that in Log4J2 Logger objects are never destroyed until the application is shut down. Does this mean (as I suspect) that our current code will create a large memory leak in Log4J2, and is there a better way to write a temporary object's logs to an individual file in Log4J2?
I'm trying to determine how to do this work. My current best idea is to write a custom Appender that writes to different files based on information in the LogEvent, but that does not seem like the correct way to do this.

I would suggest using a Routing appender with routes based on markers, that would point to a FileAppender that writes to your log file

Markers are never garbage collected, but I agree with @BIBOOunit: the routing appender is the right tool for the job together with the Context Map Lookup and a purge policy to collect the inactive appenders.

Thanks to both of you, that's very helpful.

Log4J2 supports MDCs which are key-value pairs attached to logging events.
In each job, set the MDC with job-specific details like name and timestamp before logging.
But I think you may better to don't create new Logger for each job.
also you can use dynamic file creation pattern %d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}  or job name within the filename pattern it can be help separate files.
